# more than one mesh

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

On the latest version of Blender I create chess piece - horse.
When I export it to the Unity3D, there is 2 head meshes without one.
Do you know what is wrong? I don't understand where is the problem?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It seems, that this depends on UV Editor. Now i have 8 meshes, without 2. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! :-)
Problém is only when the mesh have very much polygons.
Mesh will be separated to another two or more smaller pieces.
Solution is - simplification mesh.

Answer (score 1):

Unity have a limit for this. You cannot have more than 65,534 vertices in a mesh.
If your mesh have more than this, Unity automatically split in another mesh.